# asp.net cshtml can't run asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm following the tutorial at **asp.net mvc3** at
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part3-cs

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}

<h2>Welcome</h2>

<ul> 
   @for (int i=0; i < ViewBag.NumTimes; i++) { 
      <li>@ViewBag.Message</li> 
   } 
</ul>
```

the hellowWorldcontroller

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /HelloWorld/ 

        /*public void Index()
        {
            //return "This is my <b>default</b> action...";
            return View;
        }*/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";


            return View();
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            return View();
            //return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name + ", NumTimes is: " + numTimes);
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that in `cshtml`, it can't run the `asp.net` code, only display the static content, why?

And the `cshtml` also don't apply to the `MainContent` master page, there is only plain text without any background and button when I run the application, where's the problems?

Comment: Because you need to set `ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;` in Welcome action.

Comment: ViewBag.Title = "Welcome"; //no effect, why?

Comment: @hkinterview, for viewbag title to take effect, you need to use it in the markup - for example, `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>` in html head section. I guess that it must be located in some layout page.

Comment: @VinayC thanks, i think the tutorial is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your `for` to work, you must set the value of ViewBag in the controller.

Change the the controller like this

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
{
    ViewBag.Message = name;
    ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: how about the master page problem?

Comment: If you mean the title, it's the same, set ViewBag.Title = "hello". you will find the call in Shared/_layout.cshtml. If you mean the css, in layout check for the correct path of scripts and css

Comment: you see this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part3-cs, the content display in white area, but my application, it only displays the Welcome.cshtml

Comment: It should work if you followed the step in the tutorial (and it seems so), maybe your project is broken. Have you tried to make a new MVC3 project from scratch? Maybe you changed something by mistake in the _layout.cshtml.

Comment: i can't find _layout.cshtml, where is it?

Comment: you can find it in Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml of your project